# Failed to enable kubeflow

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubeflow

I'm trying to eable Kubeflow on microk8s (single machine installation) but I got an error:

Is the following:

```
# sudo microk8s.enable kubeflow
Enabling dns...
Enabling storage...
Enabling dashboard...
Enabling ingress...
Enabling metallb:10.64.140.43-10.64.140.49...
Waiting for DNS and storage plugins to finish setting up
Kubeflow could not be enabled:
error: timed out waiting for the condition on deployments/coredns

Command '('microk8s-kubectl.wrapper', 'wait', '--for=condition=available', '-nkube-system', 'deployment/coredns', 'deployment/hostpath-provisioner', '--timeout=10m')' returned non-zero exit status 1
Failed to enable kubeflow
```

==> Some command:

## sudo microk8s status

```
microk8s is running
addons:
dashboard: enabled
dns: enabled
gpu: enabled
ingress: enabled
metallb: enabled
metrics-server: enabled
storage: enabled
cilium: disabled
fluentd: disabled
helm: disabled
helm3: disabled
host-access: disabled
istio: disabled
jaeger: disabled
knative: disabled
kubeflow: disabled
linkerd: disabled
prometheus: disabled
rbac: disabled
registry: disabled
```

sudo snap find microk8s

```
Nom       Version  Auteur      Notes    Résumé
microk8s  v1.18.4  canonical✓  classic  Lightweight Kubernetes for workstations and appliances
```

The output of:  `microk8s.kubectl get pods -A`

```
NAMESPACE        NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
ingress          nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-mftvb     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8          18m
kube-system      coredns-588fd544bf-692tf                    0/1     Running            0          35m
kube-system      dashboard-metrics-scraper-59f5574d4-vhmq9   1/1     Running            0          31m
kube-system      hostpath-provisioner-75fdc8fccd-wqslj       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          29m
kube-system      kubernetes-dashboard-6d97855997-vl7qb       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          31m
kube-system      metrics-server-c65c9d66-6d2dp               0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          31m
metallb-system   controller-5f98465b6b-wl7ml                 1/1     Running            0          16m
metallb-system   speaker-mfpxn                               1/1     Running            0          16m
```

I have a free space disck.
Someone can help please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit the question to add logs and status of coredns and metallb pods from `kube-system` namespace

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu sorry I couldn't understand you. I'm a beginner in kubernete.

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `microk8s.kubectl get pods -A`

Comment: I'm using this link https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/workstation/getting-started-multipass/

Comment: I got this error for both commands: error loading config file "~/.kube/config": open ~/.kube/config: permission denied et the same for the other command also.
I tried to apply chmod 775 and give me the access, I got an error: chmod: access impossible: ~/.kube/config: no file or folder for this type. I verifed under the .kube folder I didn't find anythig

Comment: Add output of `microk8s.kubectl logs hostpath-provisioner-75fdc8fccd-wqslj -n kube-system` and `microk8s.kubectl logs nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-mftvb -n ingress`

Comment: For the first command: Error from server (NotFound): pods "hostpath-provisionner-75fdc8fccd-wqslj" not found

Comment: For the second command: Error from server (NotFound): pods "nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-wftvb" not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218276/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-verojoucla).

Comment: Is the link for installation good ?

Comment: sudo ufw allow in on cni0 && sudo ufw allow out on cni0 , try this command 
Refer to common issues https://microk8s.io/docs/troubleshooting