# install kubeflow is failed

Tags: kubeflow

I'm trying to install Kubeflow on my desktop. I'm following this [link](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/workstation/getting-started-multipass/)

The output of the command `microk8s.enable kubeflow` is:

```
Enabling dns...
Enabling storage...
Enabling dashboard...
Enabling ingress...
Enabling metallb:10.64.140.43-10.64.140.49...
Waiting for DNS and storage plugins to finish setting up
Kubeflow could not be enabled:
error: timed out waiting for the condition on deployments/coredns

Command '('microk8s-kubectl.wrapper', 'wait', '--for=condition=available', '-nkube-system', 'deployment/coredns', 'deployment/hostpath-provisioner', '--timeout=10m')' returned non-zero exit status 1
Failed to enable kubeflow
```

Result of `kubectl version`

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.5", GitCommit:"e6503f8d8f769ace2f338794c914a96fc335df0f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-26T03:47:41Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Result of `kubectl get pods`

```
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "pods"
```

That means I don't have a namespace ?
Some help please ?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991610/failed-to-enable-kubeflow

Comment: @tarunkhosla I just tested using this command: kubectl version --short
I displayed the Client version: V1.18.5
But still the error in the server. I think the server is not connected, because I have this error: Error from server (Not Found): the server could not find the requested resource. Could you please help me ? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the OS you are using? is it Ubuntu 20?

Comment: This seems to be caused by https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1427, reinstalling the microk8s snap may fix this, https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/1427#issuecomment-664568164